# What Christian Denomination defines the bible as its source of doctrine?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

What Christian denomination defines the bible as its source of doctrine?

> "This is not a denominational question because this is not defined as included in anyone's doctrine as a meaning." We don't handle those sort of questions here. — Caleb ([source](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/27000/what-does-light-mean-to-a-catholic-and-how-does-it-expose-the-deeds-of-darkness#comment67282_27000))

I need a Christian denomination to fulfill this perspective for the site requirements. So that I can ask a biblical question appealing to Caleb's  discernment of site regulations.

Comment: Practically every Christian denomination uses the Bible as its source of doctrine. The difference is in the interpretation, and *that* is the whole point of doctrines. Without a branch of Christianity to focus on, the answers can be from any perspective, and you end up with a voting contest, where answers are judged on belief and not accuracy/factualness. With the ten thousands of denominations today, why would you expect that you could get ***the*** "correct" answer?

Comment: Some truths need multiple perspectives to understand. My search is for the real truth and if digging through ten thousand denominations is what is needed to learn something that I feel is important. Then so be it. The truth in the end usually can be simply explained with an analogy. Therefore I do not ask for belief. I ask for "Why Belief" for in the why is the reason, and in the reason is the understanding, and in the understanding is the perspective, and from that perspective a truth can be determined. Maybe not the entire truth, but a part. With enough parts then logic can fill in the rest

Comment: You are entirely welcome to do that...just not here. The structure of the site works against what you're trying to do. The point of Stack Exchange sites is that they're intended to provide objectively correct or incorrect answers to questions. To make that work here, we (usually) have to restrict a question's scope to a denomination, otherwise there *is* no correct answer.

Comment: Ok Thank you you have been of help.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman Could you work your comments into an answer? This is a useful question for future reference (although it might need to be generalised).

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it the [**Churches of Christ**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Churches_of_Christ) and the [**Christian Church**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Church_%28Disciples_of_Christ%29) are two groups of churches that both claim the bible as the one and only source of their doctrine and authority.  Both are congregationally governed so it can be argued as to whether or not they qualify as denominations.

I believe there is now also a plethora of community churches that claim much the same, some with denominational ties slightly out of sight (and quite useful for securing loans for new building etc).